# How to write MID() query with Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, orm, substring

I want to get first 180 char of some column and I need to write query that have function like [MID() or SUBSTRING()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_mid.asp) but I have not found any feature like that in django orm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django 1.8 has [database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#module-django.db.models.functions).

[`Substr`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/database-functions/#substr) is included.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Substr
objects = MyModel.objects.annotate(first_180=Substr('fieldname', 1, 180)
for obj in objects:
    print obj.first_180
```

For database functions that are not included in Django, you can write your own [function expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions).